# Does readdir() return its results in any particular order?

Tags: perl

I have a directory that i am currently processing with a while loop. The file names are actually dates as such :

```
updates.20130831.1445.hr
updates.20140831.1445.hr
updates.20150831.1445.hr
updates.20160831.1445.hr
updates.20170831.1445.hr
```

However, somehow in my print statement, i noticed that the while loop doesn't start from the first file. rather picks the second or the 5th etc.

If while loops are sequential, why is the first file not processed first then the second, third etc ? am i missing something ?

my while loop is as such :

```
opendir(DIRECTORY, $Dir) or die $!;

while (my $file = readdir(DIRECTORY)) { 
          print "$file
          open (IN, $file) or die "error reading file: ", $file,"\n"
```

Comment: That would depend on what you'd consider the first/second/...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `readdir` builtin does not guarantee *any* order, so you would have to sort the names manually:

```
for my $file (sort readdir DIRECTORY) { ... }
```

Note that `readdir` does not output a complete path, so you have to prepend the directory name if you wish to open that file:

```
my $path = "$dir/$file";
```

Note that entries may be all kinds of file system objects including files, directories, symlinks, and named pipes. You should skip those that aren't files before trying to open them:

```
next if not -f $path;
```

In case you want to process directories, consider that the `readdir` output includes the `.` and `..` directories (current and parent dir), which you should always filter out:

```
next if $file eq "." or $file eq "..";
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want them sorted - then sort them.

`opendir` etc fetches the files in the order that they are stored on disk. Not alphabetic. It does not guarantee order

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't really make sense to ask whether `while` is sequential. A `while` loop (in any C-inspired language) just repeatedly executes a block until a particular condition tests false.

If I'm hammering a nail into a block of wood, it could be described as "while the nail protrudes, hit it with the hammer". It doesn't really make sense to ask if my hammer hits were in the correct order.

The constructs that it makes sense to ask whether they are sequential are things that operate on an ordered data structure, such as an array or list. For example, `grep`, `map`, and `foreach`. These all operate sequentially in Perl.

What it also makes sense to ask is "does `readdir()` return its results in any particular order?" The answer to this question is that it does, but it's not a particularly useful order - certainly not alphabetic/lexicographic order. If you want your files listed in a particular order, you should slurp `readdir()` into an array and then `sort` that array.

Comment: Thank you for your input on the question after reading it, just made me realize how stupid i was asking. I just didn't know the cause was sorting and unrelated to the while loop. which i do now :)